# get parent divtext with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following markup, I want to select the text inside the `.title` but **exclude** the text which is inside the `.button`.

```
<span class="title">
    Title Text
    <span class="button">Button</span>
</span>
```

I am trying following code but it selects the `.button` text also. How can I exclude that without changing the HTML.

```
$('.title').on('click', '.button', function() {
    var item = $(this).parent();
    var title = item.text();
    alert(title);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to retrieve value of the `textNode`. Try this:

```
$('.title').on('click', '.button', function() {
    var $item = $(this).parent();
    var title = $item.contents().get(0).nodeValue;
    alert(title);
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uzmab1ev/)

Comment: Apparently someone who got downvoted has downvoted all the answers, if my assumption is right.

Comment: I dont know who is downvoting, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Upvoted. Mine was sort of overkill, deleted. It's the best you can get I suppose.

Comment: What about [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/uzmab1ev/1/) and [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/uzmab1ev/2/)?

Comment: @Regent in those cases you need to use `filter()` to get textNodes only. However, the OPs code shows no need for that. If the OP clarifies he needs it, I'll amend.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan well, I just don't like that answer is not flexible one. If OP doesn't care about possible problems in future and is ready to accept this idea, I'll delete my comments without disputes.

Comment: No problem, and I completely respect that. Feel free to add you own answer which caters to those situations and I'll gladly upvote you :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this question was already asked and, if I remember correctly, we end up with something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wn4tnL29/1/). Nevertheless, I didn't find counterexample  for LcSalazar's answer, so his answer can be upvoted as well :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
$('.title').on('click', '.button', function() {
  var $item = $(this).parent();
    var title = $item.contents().get(0).nodeValue;
    alert(title);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j1zftu9a/)

Comment: Rory had updated his answer before update this was different. @A.Wolff

Comment: @ManojKumawat Ho ya, i undertsand it now ;)

Comment: @ManojKumawat.. Rory didnt edit his answer!! its just as it was posted

Comment: @NaeemShaikh first Rory answer was using `.filter()` which anyway wasn't wrong nor bad. There is no edit post history if answer is quickly edited and no one comment before next edit

Comment: I had tested that on jsfiddle that was incorrect and then i answered  @A.Wolff

Comment: @A.Wolff.... ok i m sorry i downvoted this considering copied answer.. i ll remove the downvote

Answer (score 3):

[**Yet another way**](http://jsfiddle.net/94u3rf6b/3/), using the built-in **[`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.previousSibling)** property (which includes text nodes as well) [just for information sharing].

```
$('.title').on('click', '.button', function() {
    alert(this.previousSibling.nodeValue);
    // trim the above as it can contain newlines, spaces, etc. as in the source
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can clone the element, and remove the children. Then get the text of the cloned element.

```js
$('.title').on('click', '.button', function() {
    var title = $(this).parent().clone().children().remove().end().text();
    alert(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="title">
    Title Text
    <span class="button">Button</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can replace the text retrived from the button with `''` in the parents text
http://jsfiddle.net/94u3rf6b/

```
$('.title').on('click', '.button', function() {
    var item = $(this).parent();
    var title = item.text().replace($(this).text(),'');
    alert(title);
});
```

Comment: who the hell is downvoting today

Comment: I dont know who is doing that, thanks for your answer.